# Render 3D spikes based on population data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d

I believe it can be done with 3D Analyst in ArcGIS, but is it possible to achieve something like this in QGIS?

[image: example]

Or should I generate a raster and use it as a relief map in a 3D application?

Comment: that looks like an orthographic camera (not perspective) - a good idea, with perspective height is affected by the distance to camera, so can be misleading with this type of visualisation. I've just noticed that qgis2threejs on 3.0 supports an ortho camera - I will give it a try before recommending a more technical workflow ;-)

Comment: It's not going to be easy to reproduce the mesh's detail/size in *live rendered scenes* via the *qgis2three.js* plugin, and it's a little tricky in native *three.js*, if *WebGL* is what you were aiming at. for most cases, however, I'd indeed recommend a heightmap (scale the range over a larger bit depth to ease out steps); the format depends largely on the software you use, e.g. for *three.js* it's either an image or text coded, for others it's...other formats.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this visualisation uses an orthographic camera projection.

With perspective, the LA spike will be nearer the camera and will be exaggerated to some extent, depending on where the camera is. With ortho cameras, height is consistent irrespective of distance to camera

> good news: qgis2threeJS plugin supports orthographic cameras as of QGIS3.0

The option is in menus now, under **scene > camera > orthographic**

I can't seem to get the previewer to work for rasters (I'm on a Mac - your mileage might vary if using Windows or Linux). But the **export (without preview)** works fine.

Here's a DEM done using an ortho camera in qgis2threejs

[image]

There seems to be an issue with front-plane clipping but otherwise it certainly seems to be ortho.

I've also written a python tool called [dem2obj](https://github.com/stevefaeembra/dem2obj) which converts a GDAL raster to an OBJ file, for import into meshlab or blender.

I won't post a how-to on Blender here as it isn't a GIS application, but it might be useful if you have knowledge of Blender or similar 3d tools. (Or for a heatmap, save as image using a black to white gradient and use that to displace a mesh)

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a mesh displacement from a grayscale image might be the best way to go. This will be a static image and I'm more comfortable with 3d applications like Blender and Cinema 4d, so this could work. I'll check out dem2obj, too. Thanks for your help!